# Zabbix- agent hostname no dns

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, zabbix, zabbix-agent

I have two Windows computers with agents installed. I have setup my host on Zabbix Server. The agents(from home) can communicate with Zabbix server(AWS) via VPN. VPN has been confirmed and is up.

Right now the Zabbix server is failing to communicate with agents due to hostname. From the Zabbix server terminal I cannot resolve the windows hostname due to no DNS. They are both not connected to a DC

However I added the host names with IPs to the servers **/etc/hosts**. I can now resolve, but Zabbix is still cannot find hostname

Do I really need to make the computers with agents part of domain and use DNS?

Comment: Can you provide some error logs or other info, specifically indicating which is failing - the server to poll the agent, or is the agent actively trying to push data or auto-register, and where you see the errors?  There is a requirement that certain names match, but these can be set in the config file (i.e. the security aspect), but as mentioned elsewhere zabbix does not really care about DNS unless you ask it to (e.g. by polling by DNS instead of IP).

Answer (score 0):

Zabbix has no interest in Windows domains. If the Zabbix system can resolve the names, but Zabbix fails to connect, make sure to restart the Zabbix server after making the changes to `/etc/hosts`.